# Google Maps Why does the entire page get redrawn when adding new markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a map application and i have markers that get loaded when document.ready() and i have others that get loaded when i click a button however when i click the button the markers added at the document. ready() gets lost.

When the button is clicked the entire page gets **submitted and redrawn**. This is also causing my map to move really **slow on zooming and scrolling**. Can someone assist. Under is my code. I would like to get the page running faster and i don't want to have it redrawn on every ajax request.

**Code**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">


      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(10.670044,-61.515305),
          zoom: 16,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mapOptions);


        var criminal = new google.maps.MarkerImage('resources/icons/police_new.ico',
                new google.maps.Size(100,106),
                new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                new google.maps.Point(50,50)
            );

        var companyPos = new google.maps.LatLng(10.670044,-61.515305);
        var companyMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: companyPos,
            map: map,
            icon: criminal,
            title:"First Criminal"
        });


        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            async:false,
            global:'false',
            url:'getListOfCrimeHotSpot.htm',
            headers : {Accept: 'application/json'},
            dataType: 'json'            
        }).done(function(hotspot){

            $.each(hotspot, function(i,h){
                var icon = 'resources/icons/information.ico';

                new google.maps.Marker({
                    position:new google.maps.LatLng(h.lat,h.lng),
                    map:map,
                    icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(icon, new google.maps.Size(100, 106), new google.maps.Point(0, 0), new google.maps.Point(50, 50)),
                    title: 'Crime Rating : ' + h.crimeLevel+' @ ' +h.crimeLevelCount+' / ' + h.totalNumberOfCrimes
                });
            });
        });



       return map; 


      }//end initialize


 var global_citizens;      

$(document).ready(function(){
    map = initialize();


         $('#startTracking').on('click',function(){
             $.each(global_citizens, function(i, c) {
                 console.log(c.name );

             });
         });



    $('#getCitizens').on('click', function() {
        /*var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(10.670044, -61.515305),
            zoom: 16,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };*/
         //map =  new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);  

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            async : false,
            global: 'false',
            url: 'getListOfMarkers.htm',
            headers : {Accept: 'application/json'},
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function(citizens) {
            global_citizens = citizens;

            var markerSource = [
                null,
                null,
                'resources/icons/criminal_new.ico',
                'resources/icons/victim_new.ico',
                'resources/icons/suspect_new.ico'
            ];
            $.each(citizens, function(i, c) {
                //console.log(c.name + ' | ' + c.socialSecurityNumber + ' | ' + c.lat+ ' | ' +c.lng);
                var icon = markerSource[c.citizenType];
                if(markerSource) {
                    new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(c.lat, c.lng),
                        map: map,
                        icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage( icon, new google.maps.Size(100, 106), new google.maps.Point(0, 0), new google.maps.Point(50, 50) ),
                        title: c.name +'-' +c.socialSecurityNumber
                  });
                }
            });
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

**html**

```
<body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:90%">

   <!-- MAP GOES IN HERE -->

  </div>

  <div id="toolbar">
    <button class="btn" id="getCitizens" onclick="" type="button">Get Citizens</button>
    <button class="btn" id="startTracking" onclick="" type="button">Start Tracking</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hey you have posted good amount of your Javascript code but can you please post the HTML part also which it deals with and may also a step thru such as step1: did this, step2: then did that.. sort of ;)

Comment: And if you have some developer sniffing skills check this site for google map usage with ajax and some heavy-weight map marker loading happening http://visitdublin.com/map/ (which I did before once) if you want I could post an answer based on this later on tomorrow around (12-14 hours after sorry).

Comment: @HarshBaid thanks i updated the question included the html

Comment: Also can you tell me how i can prevent the markers from getting added every time i click the button once it already exists

Comment: @Harsh Baid i got this to work i created a map variable at a global scope and kept using that instead of recreating a new one each time. As for the duplicate markers i implemented the markerMaager and used the markerManager.clearMarkers(); and it works fine

Comment: right now this is giving me alot of stress i dont know if you can help me out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409036/springmvc-ajax-request-java-io-eofexception-no-content-to-map-to-object-due-t

Answer (score 3):

The following line is causing the problem (inside this function: `$('#getCitizens').on('click', function() {`).

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
```

You are creating a new map every time the `#getCitizens` is being clicked. Use the previously instantiated map instead (the one returned by initialize function).
You wont have to reload map in that way.

Comment: Also any suggestions on why the map is moving slowly when scrolling and zooming. Any way that can be sped up

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, could you share the code in Jsfiddle.

Comment: I removed var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions); and placed var map outside scope however no icons gets drawn on map

Comment: the icons are not getting drawn

Comment: the function fires but the icon are not placed on the map

Comment: check value of the map variable when you click button!

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to reproduce the said issue may be you can try and check the following code example using Google Maps API V3.11 which is very performant and loads about 250 markers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Multiple Markers Google Maps</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.11&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        // check DOM Ready
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // execute
            (function() {
                // map options
                var options = {
                    zoom: 5,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.909736, -98.522109), // centered US
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
                    mapTypeControl: false
                };

                // init map
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), options);

                // NY and CA sample Lat / Lng
                var southWest = new google.maps.LatLng(40.744656, -74.005966);
                var northEast = new google.maps.LatLng(34.052234, -118.243685);
                var lngSpan = northEast.lng() - southWest.lng();
                var latSpan = northEast.lat() - southWest.lat();

                // set multiple marker
                for (var i = 0; i < 250; i++) {
                    // init markers
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(southWest.lat() + latSpan * Math.random(), southWest.lng() + lngSpan * Math.random()),
                        map: map,
                        title: 'Click Me ' + i
                    });

                    // process multiple info windows
                    (function(marker, i) {
                        // add click event
                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                content: 'Hello, World!!'
                            });
                            infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        });
                    })(marker, i);
                }
            })();
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 800px; height:500px;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Screen preview:

[image: Google Maps showing 250 map marker loaded]

Comment: i am looking at your position  and i am seeing the southWestand northEast coordinates can you explain that. I am moving markers on a map and i would like to keep it with in a certain country can you tell me if i can apply this same technique you used to set bounds.

Comment: My markers move based on an algorithm that generates random coordinates