# SpringMVC ajax request - java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on a SpringMVC application i requested some data from the database using an ajax call the data came back as json object. I now have to send this data back to the server for some processing and return to the form.

However i am getting an error in the browser **The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.** on investigating the error logs i saw this:

**Error Log**

```
Controller [com.crimetrack.web.MapController]
Method [public com.crimetrack.business.Marker com.crimetrack.web.MapController.getNewCoordinates(com.crimetrack.business.Marker) throws java.lang.Exception]

java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:1324)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:1275)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:941)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.readInternal(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:124)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:120)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:71)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:156)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
```

**Ajax Call**

```
 $('#getCoordinates').on('click',function(){

        $.each(global_citizens, function(i, gc){

            $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url:'getNewCoordinatesForMarkers.htm',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data:{citizens:JSON.stringify(global_citizens[i])},
                dataType: 'json',
                success:function(new_citizens){
                       $.each(new_citizens, function(i, c) {

                           console.log(c.name + ' | ' + c.socialSecurityNumber + ' | ' + c.lat+ ' | ' +c.lng);

                        });                                 
                }                           
            });             
        }); 
    });
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "getNewCoordinatesForMarkers.htm", method = {RequestMethod.GET}, headers = {"content-type=application/json"})
public @ResponseBody  Marker getNewCoordinates(@RequestBody Marker citizens)throws Exception{

    logger.info("Getting Markers");
    Marker citizenMarker = this.markerManager.getNextLocation(citizens);

    return citizenMarker;

}
```

**Marker.java**

```
public class Marker  implements Serializable{

    private int socialSecurityNumber;
    private String name;
    private int citizenType;
    private double lat;
    private double lng;

//getters and setters
```

**JSON DATA** -taken from firebug console

```
citizens{"name":"Jessie Small","lat":10.670044,"lng":-61.515305,"socialSecurityNumber":1999020214,"citizenType":3}
```

**FireBug** - content is being passed

```
Connection  close
Content-Length  3696
Content-Type    text/html;charset=utf-8
Date    Tue, 07 May 2013 05:52:09 GMT
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
Request Headers
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Content-Type    application/json
Cookie  tinymcePasteText=1; JSESSIONID=CC4F12D00C836FE0DB86D2493556275C
Host    localhost:8084
Referer http://localhost:8084/crimeTrack/crimeTrackMap.htm
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

Comment: seems like you need to register your custom binder or just simply return String instead of List<Marker>

Comment: I am now returning just an object Marker. If i return a Object instead of a List<Object> will i still need to register a custom binder? Can you point me to a good example on how to do this

Comment: i did this code but i manually construct String to json format. you want that?

Comment: yea sure i will have a look at it i have been stuck on this for the longest while. The issue is as soon as the request reaches the controller this happens it does'nt enter the controller method

Comment: I really hope that is test data otherwise you just posted the social security numbers of some unfortunate users.

Comment: haha no man its test data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the change to the controller that worked for me

```
@RequestMapping(value = "getNewCoordinatesForMarkers.htm", method = {RequestMethod.POST},produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    public @ResponseBody  Marker getNewCoordinates(@RequestBody Marker json)throws Exception{

        JSONObject jsonObj = JSONObject.fromObject(json);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

         Marker citizen = mapper.readValue(jsonObj.toString(), new TypeReference<Marker>(){});


        logger.info("Getting Markers");
        Marker citizenMarker = this.markerManager.getNextLocation(citizen);

        return citizenMarker;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

i did this code to preload getting allproduct for autocomplete function, maybe this example not fully fit with your code but i hope you can get something from this:

Controller function :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "allproduct", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=*/*")
public @ResponseBody
String productList() {
    List<Product> products = ProductDAO.INSTANCE.listProduct();
    String json = "[";
    for (int i = 0; i < products.size(); i++) {
        Product o = products.get(i);
        if (i > 0) {
            json += ",";
        }
        json += "{\"value\":\"" + o.getCode() + "\",\"label\":\""
                + o.getCode() + " - " + o.getProvider() + " - "
                + o.getNominal() + "\",\"price\":\""
                + o.getPrice() + "\",\"cost\":\"" + o.getCost() + "\"}";
    }
    json += "]";
    System.out.println(json);
    return json;
}
```

in my jsp, i use jquery to call that function :

```
$.getJSON('/product/allproduct', function(json) {
    $("#product").autocomplete({
        source : json,
        select : function(event, ui) {
            $("#product").val(ui.item.value);
            $("#kredit").val(ui.item.cost);
            $("#price").val(ui.item.price);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

take a look for  [json format here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). Example for an array :

```
[
    {
        "name": "Jason",
        "number": "10"
    },
    {
        "name": "Jimmy",
        "number": "11"
    }
]
```

Comment: its processing json on the server thats give the issue but thanks for you code

Comment: hey did u take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921736/parsing-json-into-java-objects-in-spring-mvc ?

Comment: yep i saw this question i do not understand how to register a custom data binder for this class can you help with that

Comment: but your errors didnt show binding error. how if u change param Marker citizens to straight String first.. did u will get that value? also take a look http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/ for converting json to Java Object

Comment: Hey thanks i did a conversion from json object to java object and it works for me. Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

You'll get that error if you don't include "Content-Length" in the header.